# Input row of 2D array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array and want to write a row all at once time instead of through a loop.

How do I do this?

```
double mat[3][3];

row1={1,2,3}
row2={4,5,6}
row3={7,8,9}
```

What I want to write is

```
mat[0]={1,2,3}
```

but I know that's not the correct syntax. Does anyone know what is?

I'm working in C.

Thanks!

Comment: it would be very helpful to know which language you refer to...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your rows are defined like the following:

```
double row1[] = { 1, 3, 5 };
```

Then you can copy the entire row to your 2D array using memcpy().

```
#include <string.h>

memcpy( mat[0], row1, 3 * sizeof(double) );
```